# NGINX: Unable to load CSS and Images while launching web page

Tags: html, css, image, nginx

I have web page with HTML, JS and CSS. I am launching this application in existing domain [for example https://example.com/(#mynewwebpage#)] by setting up rule in my Load Balancer. Page loads fine without any issue but my css and images are unable to load. This is how my NGINX configuration looks like and i believe something need to correct in NGINX.
NGINX entry:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

 

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

 

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

 

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

 

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

 

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

 

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

 

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

 

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

 

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

 

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location /nextgen {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

 

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

 

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

 

}
```

Here is my INDEX html code
**https://example.com/nextgen** [Running URL, Note: domain name is just for illustration only]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/11.0.1/modules/heatmap.min.js" integrity="sha512-UnB4oMqreoARmg5J+Z75xQj0EVIIfV3ciCNGOyZ/m6HgNcg6eztp06jio3syCn4lTsMcbWMXE0zt+XqG3seehA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles3.css" />

<!-- <div class="row">
<img id="logo" class="row-content" src="Company-logo.png" width="112" height="110">
<div id="header2" class="row-content row-content-text" width="112" height="110">Metrics Page Mock-up</div>
<div class="dropdown row-content">
    <button class="dropbtn row-content">Layouts</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="graph_nav_site.html">2 2 2</a>
        <a href="graph_123.html">1 2 3</a>
        <a href="graph_33.html">3 3</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>  -->
<!--row tag-->


<header class="header">
<div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" class="row-content" src="images/LSEG-stacked-logo.png" width="112" height="110" alt="logo">
  <span class="title">LSEG Metrics Dashboard</span>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <button class="menu-btn">Layouts</button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="graph_123.html">1 2 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2 2 2</a></li>
      <li id="last_drop"><a href="graph_toggle.html">toggle</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="row">
    <div>Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Here **css/styles3.css** and **images/Company-logo.png** unable to load

Error Description:

***GET https://example.com/Company-logo.png 503 (Service Unavailable)
GET https://example.com/styles3.css net::ERR_ABORTED 503 (Service Unavailable)***

Based on reply from @Griffin I applied the change which shows 200 for CSS and Image but page doesn't load with css and image and here is the screenshot for better clarification.
[Screenshot: current look of the issue page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMeE3.png)

[Screenshot: Response Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgrvW.png)

Comment: Not sure but I think that you should change "location /nextgen" into "location /nextgen/"

Comment: @Griffin based on this change, i can see CSS and and Images with 200 but page still doesn't reflect with change. Added screenshot above  to give current look of the issue.

Comment: 200 mean that the request worked so this is odd. Can you add another screenshot with the response tab?

Comment: @Griffin, sorry for late response but response tab have nothing "This request has no response data available".
Even when i open the image page [https://example.com/nextgen/Company-logo.png", it opens the same application page but not the image. Same with CSS path. Added the response tab image for reference. Thank you.